# При редактировании статьи, как повторно отправить имя изображения

Tags: php, html, mysql, форма

Помогите, пожалуйста. Никак не могу при редактировании статьи придумать, как "не потерять" изображение из формы. При редактировании оно просто теряется.

```html
<?php   //ФАЙЛ IMAGEPROC.PHP
// Перезапишем переменные для удобства
$filePath  = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
$errorCode = $_FILES['upload']['error'];
// Проверим на ошибки
//if ($errorCode !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK || !is_uploaded_file($filePath)) {
    // Массив с названиями ошибок
 //   $errorMessages = [
 //       UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE   => 'Размер файла превысил значение upload_max_filesize в конфигурации PHP.',
 //       UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE  => 'Размер загружаемого файла превысил значение MAX_FILE_SIZE в HTML-форме.',
 //       UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL    => 'Загружаемый файл был получен только частично.',
 //       UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE    => 'Файл не был загружен.',
 //       UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR => 'Отсутствует временная папка.',
 //       UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE => 'Не удалось записать файл на диск.',
 //       UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION  => 'PHP-расширение остановило загрузку файла.',
 //   ];
    // Зададим неизвестную ошибку
 //   $unknownMessage = 'При загрузке файла произошла неизвестная ошибка.';
    // Если в массиве нет кода ошибки, скажем, что ошибка неизвестна
 //   $outputMessage = isset($errorMessages[$errorCode]) ? $errorMessages[$errorCode] : $unknownMessage;
    // Выведем название ошибки
  //  die($outputMessage);
//}
// Создадим ресурс FileInfo, проверяющая MIME-тип файла
$fi = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
// Получим MIME-тип
$mime = (string) finfo_file($fi, $filePath);
// Закроем ресурс
finfo_close($fi);
// Проверим ключевое слово image (image/jpeg, image/png и т. д.)
if (strpos($mime, 'image') === false) die('Можно загружать только изображения.');
// Результат функции запишем в переменную
$image = getimagesize($filePath);
// Зададим ограничения для картинок
$limitBytes  = 1024 * 1024 * 20;
$limitWidth  = 3500;
$limitHeight = 3500;
// Проверим нужные параметры
if (filesize($filePath) > $limitBytes) die('Размер изображения не должен превышать 5 Мбайт.');
if ($image[1] > $limitHeight)          die('Высота изображения не должна превышать 3500 точек.');
if ($image[0] > $limitWidth)           die('Ширина изображения не должна превышать 3500 точек.');
// Сгенерируем новое имя файла на основе MD5-хеша
$name = md5_file($filePath);
// Сгенерируем расширение файла на основе типа картинки
$extension = image_type_to_extension($image[2]);
// Сократим .jpeg до .jpg
$format = str_replace('jpeg', 'jpg', $extension);
// Переместим картинку с новым именем и расширением в папку /files
if (!move_uploaded_file($filePath, __DIR__ . '/files/' . $name.$format)) {
    die('При записи изображения на диск произошла ошибка.');
};
$image = $name.$format;
?>
```

```html
 //ФАЙЛ INDEX.PHP
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
ini_set('display_errors',1);
    require("auth.php");
    require_once("../database.php");
    require_once("../models/articles.php");

    $link = db_connect();

$article['title']='';       //это, чтобы не выдавало сообщение об ошибке в выводе статей
$article['data']='';
$article['content']='';
$article['author']='';
$article['image']='';


//-------------обработчик изображения----------
if(!empty($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'])) {
    require_once ("../imageproc.php");
};

// --------------- логика -----------------
    if (isset($_GET['action']))                 //Проверяет, нажата ли какая-либо кнопка действий
        $action = $_GET['action'];
    else
        $action ="";                    

    if ($action == "add"){                     // Если нажато "добавить статью", то вызываем функцию "новая статья" (из подключенного файла models.php)
        if (!empty($_POST)){
            article_new($link, $_POST['title'], $_POST['content'], $_POST['data'], $image);
            header("Location: index.php");
        }

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>Мой первый блог</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Мой первый блог</h1>
            <h3>Форма добавления статьи</h3>
            <div>
                <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="index.php?action=<?=$_GET['action']?>&id=<?=$_GET['id']?>" >
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label>
                        Название
                        <input type="text" name="title" value="<?=$article['title']?>" class="form-control" autofocus required>
                    </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label>
                        Дата
                        <input type="date" name="data" value="<?=$article['data']?>" class="form-control" required>
                    </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label>
                        Содержимое
                        <textarea name="content" class="form-control" required><?=$article['content']?></textarea>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="file" name="upload" value=<?=$article['image']?>>
                    </label> <br/>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Сохранить" class="btn">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
                <p>Мой первый блог<br>Copyright &copy; 2016</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
        include("../views/article_admin.php");    
    }
    else if ($action == "edit"){                //Если нажато "редактировать", то вызываем функцию "редактировать стьатью""
        if (!isset($_GET['id']))
            header("Location: index.php");
        $id = (int)$_GET['id'];

        if (!empty($_POST) && $id > 0){
            article_edit($link, $id, $_POST['title'], $_POST['content'], $_POST['data'], $image);
            header("Location: index.php");
        }

        $article = article_get($link, $id);
        include("../views/article_admin.php");
    } else if ($action == "delete"){            //Если нажато "удалить", то вызываем функцию "удаления"
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        article_delete($link, $id);
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
    else{
        $articles = article_all($link);             // Иначе вывести все статьи списком(вызов соответствующей функции)
        include("../views/articles_admin.php");
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Хранить имя уже существующего изображения в `<input type="hidden">`, и при сохранении, если нет нового из `type="file"`, использовать его

```html
...
<label>
    <input type="file" name="upload">
    <input type="hidden" name="image" value="<?=$article['image']?>">
</label>
...
```

Или просто, если не загружено изображение - не менять старое при сохранении

Comment: Спасибо, Nikita Umnov! Помогло использование type="hidden". Я просто не знал как осуществить это не изменение старого))